# How to Create a help doc in Netbean's documentation window

Tags: java, javadoc, netbeans-7

I want to know  how to make a java help doc in Netbeans.something like this below image.
For every inbuilt functions and properties there have certain notes(Help docs).But I want to create my own help docs for my functions or classes.Is it possible to create such type of docs in netbeans.

[image]

Any answer is acceptable..

Regds..

Comment: That's standard JavaDoc. Read the Java tutorial.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I know thats standard docs,but sir is it possible to make ourown doc files and attached to my class or functions

Comment: You need to add the JavaDocs in your source code. NetBeans will automatically display them. This is documented in the NetBeans manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/working_nbeans.htm#A1165923

Comment: How to add/  java doc..give me an answer with an example..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs can automatically extract javadoc from source code or show directly from attached javadocs and show it for you in popup window on some actions (ctrl+q on IntelliJ IDEA).

First you have to write that javadoc for your element (class, method, field, etc) and then you can see this javadoc for described element in popup window of your IDE along with other javadocs.

**Example in IntelliJ IDEA:**

Class is written without javadoc. Popup window for javadoc in IDE:
[image]
[image]
No doc, because it is not written.

Lets write javadoc for class and method. What shows popup window now?
[image]
[image]
I think it must be the same for NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Thanks for this answer,But friend Iwant to create java doc for my own functions in my project,,Any Idea..??

Comment: @Vijay Hey, are you ok? Do you see what we have wrote you? Write javadoc for your functions!!!

Comment: Ok..I mean it.I get U..But In my case its not working in my class..I dont know what is the reason.and I also want to create javadoc for my functions() too..